# testing models with builds or matcher in factory girl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, factory-bot, rspec-rails

I have the following factory for patient_allergies

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :patient_allergy do
    patient
    name 'Peanuts'
  end
end
```

The following factory for patient_allergy_reactions

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :patient_allergy_reaction do
    patient_allergy
    name 'Fever'
    severity 'High'
  end
end
```

The model for patient_allergy looks like this:

```
class PatientAllergy < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :patient
  has_many :patient_allergy_reactions
end
```

the model for patient_allergy_reaction looks like this:

```
class PatientAllergyReaction < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :patient_allergy
end
```

My model tests look this:

```
it 'returns correct allergies with reactions' do
    #create an allergy
    allergy_name = 'Peanuts'
    patient_allergy = create(:patient_allergy, name: allergy_name, patient: patient)

    #create a allergy reaction
    reaction_name = 'Fever'
    reaction_severity = 'Low'
    allergy_reaction = create(:patient_allergy_reaction, name: reaction_name, severity: reaction_severity, patient_allergy: patient_allergy)

    expect(patient.patient_allergies.size).to eq(1)
    expect(patient.patient_allergies[0]).to eq(patient_allergy)
    expect(patient.patient_allergies[0].patient_allergy_reactions[0]).to eq(allergy_reaction)
  end
```

The above works fine but doesnt seem to add much value.
  I am trying to figure out a way to use build and traits for the above test.
  Else, is there a way to use the expect(patient).to have_many(:patient_allergies) matcher or something.

It would be really helpful if i could understand testing my models with factory girl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*The above works fine but doesnt seem to add much value*

Agreed. Your model specs should test methods that you write, instead of testing the behavior of Rails.

If you want to test your associations, you can check out [shoulda-matchers](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers), which has standard tests for Rails models.

Comment: is there a way  to tests for my above code without shoulda. I dont want to use an external gem in this case.

Comment: Look at the code for should_matchers (https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers/blob/master/lib/shoulda/matchers/active_record/association_matcher.rb). Notice that it is not creating and saving model instances -- it only tests that you have setup your models appropriately, not that the ActiveRecord code itself works. Rails has its own tests for that.